How to upload image from expo-image-picker to Express.js that is using multer
as title says, I am trying to upload picture using expo-image-picker and express.js backend
Expo code:
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 4],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].fileName);
      console.log(result.assets[0].fileName);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", {
        filename: result.fileName,
        mimetype: result.mimeType,
        size: result.fileSize, 
      });

      axios
        .post(`http://${apiURL}:8000/api/upload`, formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("archivo enviado");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Archivo no enviado", err);
        });
    }
  };

Express code
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./storage/imgs");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
    console.log(file);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/upload", upload.single("archivo"), (req, res) => {
  if (req.file) {
    res.json({
      message: "Imagen subida con éxito",
      file: req.file,
    });
    console.log(req.file);
  } else {
    const message = "No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo";
    res.status(400).json({ message });
  }
});

When I test uploading image only with backend using Postman all works well.
The error is [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]

I haven't used with axios, but this did works with fetch,
First you need to add the base64 option to launchImageLibraryAsync
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 4],
    quality: 1,
    base64:true
});

We need to have a blob containing the image data
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(result.base64,"base64");
const imageBlob = new Blob([imageBuffer],{type}); // type is your image format eg: image/png
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file",imageBlob,"imageName."+imageExtention);

Have a look at this for more help and possibly a more elegant solution.
